# How to give USB access to VirtualBox when non-root

Tags: usb, virtualbox, permissions

I'm a member of vboxusers group. I installed the extension pack. When running VirtualBox as non-root, USB devices are visible but grayed-out. When running VirtualBox as root then it works fine.

How to add access to USB devices when running virtualbox as non-root?

OS: Lubuntu 12.04, VirtualBox 4.3.2r90405 with extension pack.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what worked for me was to use synaptic to completely uninstall (including configuration files) the commercial virtual-box 4.3 and install the virtualbox (open source edition).  I then had to uncheck usb2 support, but my devices were then found (not grayed out) and I didn't need to use root either.

Comment: I'm the original poster and I have switched to Debian sid a while ago... From what I remember the non-root user need to be added to the vboxusers group AND one of: {add the non privileged user to the udev group to grant access to any USB devices }, {Add the non privileged user to the same group as the device (there is many)}, {change the permission of the device: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141255/give-a-specific-user-permissions-to-a-device-without-giving-access-to-other-user}. Finally reboot or create new session + reload the vbox driver.

Comment: However the easiest solution is the one you described since the install script then take care of fixing permission. I might be wrong but maybe you get only usb1 speed which is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I am re-posting [the solution](https://superuser.com/a/1508951/544377) that worked for me:

After numerous searching I've concluded with the help of [this wiki](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/VirtualBox-udev-integration) to the [below script](https://gist.github.com/gon1332/70422af1fa6bed497964701b81fef124) that fixed the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Heavily inspired by https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/VirtualBox-udev-integration
#

vbox_usbnode_path=$(find / -name VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh 2> /dev/null | head -n 1)
if [[ -z $vbox_usbnode_path ]]; then
    echo Warning: VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh file has not been found.
    exit 1
fi

chmod 755 $vbox_usbnode_path
chown root:root $vbox_usbnode_path

vboxusers_gid=$(getent group vboxusers | awk -F: '{printf "%d\n", $3}')

vbox_rules="SUBSYSTEM==\"usb_device\", ACTION==\"add\", RUN+=\"$vbox_usbnode_path \$major \$minor \$attr{bDeviceClass} $vboxusers_gid\"
SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", ACTION==\"add\", ENV{DEVTYPE}==\"usb_device\", RUN+=\"$vbox_usbnode_path \$major \$minor \$attr{bDeviceClass} $vboxusers_gid\"
SUBSYSTEM==\"usb_device\", ACTION==\"remove\", RUN+=\"$vbox_usbnode_path --remove \$major \$minor\"
SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", ACTION==\"remove\", ENV{DEVTYPE}==\"usb_device\", RUN+=\"$vbox_usbnode_path --remove \$major \$minor\""

echo "$vbox_rules" > /etc/udev/rules.d/virtualbox.rules
rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/*-virtualbox.rules
udevadm control --reload
adduser `logname` vboxusers

echo All actions succeeded.
echo Log out and log in to see if the issue go fixed.
```

Be sure to have [VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) installed and at least USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller enabled at VM's USB settings.

After these, run the above script with `sudo`.