# USB support with VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, usb, virtualbox

This isn't really a question but more like my frustration and criticism -

After spending countless hours, searching web for answer, there seems to be a lot of confusion about the Virtual Box versions i.e. `OSE` - `PUEL`and I still don't know which version I am using, I mean i know it is `4.3.6r91406` but which one

here is one post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack/41487#41487) describing steps to install which is exactly what I followed `PUEL` and 2nd post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) saying it is only possible with `OSE` and 3rd post suggesting different solution altogether [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370094/how-to-give-usb-access-to-virtualbox-when-non-root)

I still managed to use USB support with VM, without deleting or installing - I used USB as it is now.

So, what is criteria for maintaining these forums and who does it ? or may be I did not use it the way it is meant to be ?!

Comment: @Takkat - it is actually the first image that is the most confusing .. USB settings in Virtual Box Manager are always greyed out - you have to add USB device from RHS using `+` sign

Answer (score 0):

USB support will work without the extension package - but only 1.1
Seems like they don't want to make the modules for usb 2.0 open source, so they offer it as extension pack.

Comment: all the distraction surrounding the process and everybody referencing different names, versions - [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is referencing different names - it is  pointless effort that goes into just getting it to work.

Comment: I think this because Oracle (Sun previous) was releasing 2 different edition of VirtualBox due to some features (PXE, VNC, Enhanced USB) need non-free licenses  But later, It separated those features into plug-ins which are distributed on the official website, so there is only Open Source VirtualBox edition. Due to license, They can not be packaged for Ubuntu or other free distributions. Making such change left much outdated tutorials, blogs,...